# Save mapView state

Tags: android, google-maps

How to save state of MapView in 3 situation 1) Rotate the device 2) Start new fragment and return to previous 3) Start new Fragment and rotate device. The following code resolves 2 Event:

```
public void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    mMapView.onPause();
    View view = mActivity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    super.onPause();
    cameraPosition = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

This for 1 event:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

    if(mSearchString !=null && !mSearchString.equals("")) {
        outState.putString("search", mSearchString);
    }

    final Bundle mapViewSaveState = new Bundle();

    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewSaveState);

    outState.putBoolean("firstStart", false);

    outState.putBundle("mapState", mapViewSaveState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

But in 3 event mMapView == null and NPE. How to solve?

Comment: is your activity restarting while changing the orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent activity from restarting, simply add this to your manifest.

into your activity tag

```
<activity
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
/>
```

**EDIT:**

This code will load the layout as per your **orientation changes**.

Add this code in your **activity**:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscapeView);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.portraitView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not differently but in addition to it if you want separate layout for your landscape view of activity, you can check my updated answer..

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the two main task while change the orientation of device
 1>In activity at manifest file you have to put this code

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

2> you have to override

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putCharSequence("key", "save the value"  );
}
```

and now check in on create of activity

```
if(bundle !=null)
{
 String saveValue=bundle.getCharSequence("key");
}
```

now use saveValue after orientation.